# Access Central Directory in ZIP file

Tags: java

So I am wondering, how do you access the Central Directory of a ZIP file in Java, to access the ZIP's entry headers?

Googled around but could not find much of a info about the matter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open the [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) and use its [`entries`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries--) method to get a list of [`ZipEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) instances.

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("/path/to/the/file.zip");
for (ZipEntry entry : zf.entries() {
    // Use the entry here
}
```

Comment: But if the ZIP file is int the WEB, and I dont want to download it?

Comment: @Veske: There's absolutely nothing about that in your question. As far as I know, `ZipFile` doesn't have a stream-based constructor, so unless there's another non-JDK project for this (which seems likely), I don't see getting around downloading first.